# Promise never resolves - only get another promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm attempting to make a call to an outside service. The call seems to go through successfully, but all I get returned is a Promise, and if I access a property, it returns another Promise. Would appreciate another set of eyes to see what I'm doing wrong (I'm a Java developer writing React for the first time).

```
function retrieveUserProfile() {
    const result = API.fetchProfile({
    include: 'field1, field2',
  });
  return result;
}

let userProfile = retrieveUserProfile()
  .then((result) => {
    return result.data;
  })
```

`userProfile` is yet another promise. Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more context.

Comment: `await` it or call `then` on it.

Comment: In the second block of code, I do call "then".

Comment: @CNDyson so any code that needs to use the result you'll put inside the `(result) => { /*... */ }` function

Comment: @NicholasTower That was the tip I needed! Please make your comment an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Promises in JavaScript are boxes containing values which are either resolved, rejected or pending.

They can only be accessed via the `.then()` (for resolved values) or `.catch()` (for rejected values) methods.

Returning a value from either of them will create a new Promise box with a new value in it.

```js
const promise5 = Promise.resolve(5) // promise5 is a Promise box with `5` in it
const promise10 = promise5.then(n => n*2); // promise5 is a Promise box with `10` in it
```

Accessing the value without using `then()` is not possible, because a resolved value might only exist in the future.

JavaScript promises syntax sugar for working with promises: async/await

```js
const resolved5 = await Promise.resolve(5) // resolved10 is `5`
const resolved10 = resolved5*2; // resolved10 is `10`
```

but this turns the wrapping function into a Promise, since marking any function using `await` with `async` is required:

```js
async myAsyncFunction() { // returns a Promise
   const resolved5 = await Promise.resolve(5)
   const resolved10 = resolved5*2;
   // resolved10 is a number here, not a Promise
   // but will be wrapped in a Promise when returned.
   return resolved10;
}
```